# "internal class" not compiling in one library, but working in a new class library

Tags: c#

I have an internal attribute that is not visible in the assembly it's defined in.

The attribute

```
namespace Stuff {

  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
    internal sealed class LogActionsAttribute : Attribute {

        internal LogActionsAttribute() { }
    }
}
```

This class is defined in the same assembly and produces a compile error.

```
namespace OtherStuff {

  [Stuff.LogActionsAttribute]
    class MyClass {

        void D() {


        }
    }

}
```

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'LogActionsAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Stuff' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that type is inside the project, then it is probably a namespace collision; try:

```
[global::Stuff.LogActions]
class MyClass { ... }
```

this avoids conflicts with `Stuff` in other namespaces.

Comment: I'm not sure how there could be a namespace collision. They are my custom namespaces. I tried your suggestion and it's still not visible. Any other ideas?

Comment: @SirPsycho - have you got any pre-compiler `#if` ? Basically, is that class **definitely getting compiled**?

Comment: @SirPsycho - and is it definitely inherited from `System.Attribute`? and not some other class called `Attribute`?

Comment: Thanks Marc. It seems VS created my new .cs file with Build Action set to Content.